# How do I draw the \cong symbol that is labelled?

Tags: overset

I'd like to type out something to the effect of the below image. But I am not completely sure how to label the `\cong`.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `amsmath` provides a macro `\overset`, which works like LaTeX's `\stackrel` but is somewhat more general (`\stackrel` expects only a binary relation, `\overset` works with everything).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$A \overset{\varphi}{\cong} B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here, I chose to add the `\varphi` in `\scriptscriptstyle`, but one could change that to `\scriptstyle` to suit.  I also chose a 1pt stacking gap, which can also be changed to suit.

If one wants to prevent an oversized overstack from messing with the natural spacing of `\cong`, then invoke `\def\useanchorwidth{T}` prior to the event, as shown in the 2nd example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
A \mathrel{\stackon[1pt]{\cong}{\scriptscriptstyle\varphi}} B
\]
\[
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
A \mathrel{\stackon[1pt]{\cong}{\scriptscriptstyle xyz}} B
\]
\[
A \cong B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This, of course, can be formulated as a macro

```
\newcommand\overcong[1][]{%
  \mathrel{\stackengine{1pt}{\cong}{\scriptscriptstyle #1}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
}
```

with usage `A \overcong[xyz] B`.