# Text above isomorphism symbol

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, commutative-diagrams

When writing that two objects are isomorphic, I use `X \cong Y`.

Sometimes however, it is necessary to specify the type of isomorphism in question. I wish to do this with text above/below the isomorphism symbol, in much the same way that one can use `\xrightarrow{}` to insert text above an arrow indicating a map from X to Y.

Using `X \cong_{text} Y` or `X \cong^{text} Y` doesn't do exactly what I want, because this gives me subscript/superscript, which are offset from the `\cong` symbol. What I want is text that appears directly above/below the isomorphism symbol, like `\xrightarrow`.

What can I do to make that happen?

Comment: Is it similar to this question, like a starting point? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306668/how-do-i-draw-the-cong-symbol-that-is-labelled. If it is possibile, please can you put a MWE or a minimal screenshot in LaTeX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

$A\overset{a}{\cong}B, c\underset{b}{\cong}D$

\end{document}
```

It is possible to use `\text` from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

$A\overset{\text{over}}{\cong}B, c\underset{\text{under}}{\cong}D$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like that indeed. Thank you :)

Comment: @Matt It has been a pleasure to help you. :-) If you need us, we are all here to help you.